# Can you Simplify a "Not Expression" in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
(defn eval-not

  [input]

 (cond

(and (seq? (second input)) (= 'and (first (second input)))) ;(do x here which -> (or (not x) (not y))
))
```

The user will type (eval-not '(not (and x y))) and I want it to return => (or (not x) (not y)). Is this possible while maintaining the cond-usage. Would prefer to not use macros, thanks.

Comment: What do you think you're going to get for `input` if you're not using macros?

Comment: A macro could do this, but why?  Also, only a macro can re-write code, which is what you are asking).

Comment: A function could accept the quoted list `'(not (and x y))` and return the quoted list `'(or (not x) (not y))`, which I think is what is desired. The real problem is that there's no question here except "is it possible?", with no attempt made or research shown.

Comment: My attempt is the code written above. Am asking how to get started doing so

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about list manipulation following the rules of boolean operations. No need to learn about macros.

You started on the right track but need to figure out:

- the rules to be applied (eg. `not` over `and` looks like `(not (and x y))` → `(or (not x) (not y)`) but also for `not` over `not`, `or` and so on,
- when to apply recursion (eg. `not` can be distributed if the argument is a sequence, but non-sequences end the recursion) and call `eval-not` again, carefully.

Keep in mind that the return value of your function will be list, so you need to build a list as the return value. For your first case, your list needs to start with the symbol `or`, so the return value next to your first test expression in the `cond` will look like:

```clj
(list 'or (eval-not (list 'not x)) (eval-not (list 'not y)))
```

... where `x` and `y` are the actual parts of the input that go after the `and` in the second element of `input`.

I recommend you check if the input is itself a sequence, so you can start giving names to those parts because otherwise the code gets messy really soon.

With the above, the code starts looking like this:

```clj
(defn eval-not [input]

  (cond

    ;; when these happen
    (and (= 'not (first input))
         (seq? (second input))
         (= 'and (first (second input))))
      ;; then
      (let [x (nth (second input) 1)
            y (nth (second input) 2)]
        ;; distribute `not` over `and` here...

    ;; other cases...
    ))
```

I hope this helps without solving the homework for you.